# Problem with Logistic regression using categorial variables

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I have a problem with Logistic regression using categorial variables. This my training datasets :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that logistic regression cannot make use of features which are strings. To use these features in your model you have to convert them to values first by encoding them. There are several ways of encoding the string values into numerical values, examples of this are using a [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), and [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can separate both the continuous and categorical features. Then use pd.get_dummies() to encode the categorical features and convert them into a form that is understood by model. Model Doesn't understand Strings, you need to pass the values as numeric.

```
continuous =[features for features in df.columns if df[features].dtype!='O']
# create continuous features df
continuous =df[list of continuous features]
# create categoricalfeatures df
df_categorical=df[list of categorical features]
# encode categorical features
dummie=pd.get_dummies(df_categorical, drop_first=True)
# create final df
final=pd.concat([dummie,continuous ],axis=1)
# separate training and target variables from data
x=final.drop(['target_variable'],axis=1)
y=final['target_variable']
# create train and test split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x, y,
    test_size=0.3,
    random_state=10)
```

Now you can use X_train, y_train as training data for your model. This will solve your problem.